# Weak Entity Many to Many ERD to Relations

Tags: database, entity-relationship, relation, erd

Say I have an entity department with PK deptNo and a weak entity course with partial key courseNo.

If a relationship exists between the two that is many to many with a partial key attribute (stream). How would I turn this into relations from an ERD.

I've create tables below:

Department deptNo(PK), deptMgr, phoneNo

Course deptNo(PK), courseNo(PK), professor

Then I know I need to create another table for the many to many.

DeptCourse D_deptNo(PK), C_deptNo(PK), courseNo(PK), stream(PK)

I am not sure if my relation DeptCourses should only have one deptNo attribute or is it correct to include both?

Is this the correct relation mapping of this ERD relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this simple diagram:

[image]

- You need to keep information on the Department and the Courses.
- Do not put the Department PK as a foreign key in the Course table.
- The link between Department and Course is done in a link table, which contains only the PK from the other two tables.
- The link table can contain more information.  Ex. the schedule for each course.
- The link table should also link the professor.  Nothing forces a course to have one and only one professor.  It could change between terms.

You should model your database from the business logic and requirements of your client.  Here you are asking to review your solution, without describing the actual requirements (known as an XY problem).

Comment: I understand what you are saying but in the diagram I am working from Department owns Courses and there is two separate relationships I am trying to model between them. The identifying relationship and this many to many relationship. This is not a database I am designing. The design is meant to be strange as it is from a previous exam I am studying from. What's throwing me off is whether or not to use two deptNo one as FK for Department and one FK fo rCourse? Seems sloppy.

Comment: Your question has "database" tag.  Anyway, you did not specify why you want to have 2 links between Department and Course.  Cases where this is required are rare, and the relations set up this way do not respect normal forms.

Comment: Oops must have mistagged it. I agree. My professor purposely asks trick questions which are not applicable in real life.